# What's a good brief introduction to Mono/.NET programming?

Tags: .net, mono

I am quite impressed by the Mono features, especially by the portability of the library. I think I'll give it a try soon or later and I'd need some directions to find an introduction to Mono/.NET programming. Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: <cynical>Don't hold your breath about Mono</cynical> It was a huge disappointment to me to see how many things won't work. Only thing I can recommend is develop under linux first then windows, it'll be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly Mono programming is not any different classical .NET programming.

You can only use C# in a decent way, non of the other .NET languages. Even though Mono claims VB.NET support it's far from being a reasonable compiler or reasonable IL support. VB.NET mostly experimental.

If your main OS is Windows easiest way to start downloading the Mono VmWare - http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html - openSuse

Enviroment is ready kick start Mono development.

Try [Mono Start page](http://mono-project.com/Start) for tips

Don't forget you can't use COM.

Best way to proceed code it in Mono (IDE is terrible after VS.NET) then porting it Windows.

Comment: Although you cannot use COM, you can use the winforms WebBrowser Control, which is implemented using Mozilla's Gecko.

VB.Net is unfortunately still at the VB.Net 8 version, not the VB.Net 9 version.

Comment: @jpobst I didn't know WebBrowser Control implementation, that's kind of cool :) VB.NET 8 version is not the problem the problem is compiler is seriously bad and support VB DLLs is a bit flaky. You can't code in compiler if it gives an "Unknown Error" without a line number!

Comment: Ah, that would suck.  I did not know the VB.Net compiler was that bad.  On the plus side, you can compile with MS's VB compiler and use that on Mono.  However, that will not get you around missing stuff in the VB support dll.

Comment: I really love the idea of Mono, it's such a hard job and quite impressive. Don't want to disrespect the developers. So I keep my hopes high :) Hopefully they'll fix those show stoppers soon.

Answer (score 1):

Great Recommendations by Slough. I've found the [Mono Getting Started Guide](http://mono-project.com/Start) and the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) very helpful in understanding it's history, how it works, and how to get started:

- [Mono Project website](http://mono-project.com/), especially the Getting Started guide
- [Mono (software) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software))

Answer (score 0):

I found Petzold's free ebook [.NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/DotNetBookZero11.pdf) useful as an introduction to .Net programming.